# How to add extra hosts entries in helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

So i'm deploying my application stack on kubernetes sing helm charts and now i need to add some dependant server ip's and hostnames inside my pods /etc/hosts file so need help on this scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As standing in documentation you can add extra hosts to POD by using [host aliases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/) feature

Example from docs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
    - "bar.local"
  - ip: "10.1.2.3"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.remote"
    - "bar.remote"
  containers:
  - name: cat-hosts
    image: busybox
    command:
    - cat
    args:
    - "/etc/hosts"
```

Answer (score 12):

A helm templated solution to the original question. I tested this with helm 3.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
    {{- with .Values.hostAliases }}
      hostAliases:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

For values such as:

```
hostAliases:
  - ip: "10.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "host.domain.com"
```

If the hostAliases is omitted or commented out in the values, the hostAliases section is omitted when the template is rendered.

Comment: This solution will create wrong format in the first element of list. The following code works for me on helm v3.5.0 ```hostAliases: {{- .Values.hostAliases | toYaml | nindent 8 }} ```

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes provides a [DNS service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) that all pods get to use.  In turn, you can define an [ExternalName service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) that just defines a DNS record.  Once you do that, your pods can talk to that service the same way they'd talk to any other Kubernetes service, and reach whatever server.

You could deploy a set of ExternalName services globally.  You could do it in a Helm chart too, if you wanted, something like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Name }}-foo
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: {{ .Values.fooHostname }}
```

The practice I've learned is that you should avoid using `/etc/hosts` if at all possible.