# Kubernetes Route to Service using Ingress hostname | Keycloak

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

What field should I add to the service / ingress yaml so that I can reach the service from another pod in the same cluster using its associated (external) hostname specified in ingress?

I'm using microk8s with the default ingress class (nginx), and I need a solution that works in any kubernetes platform (azure, gke, aks)

I need to reach my authentication server (keycloak) from my nodejs application, using ingress hostname. I can't use service name, because the token validation would fail (JWT ISS checking).

thanks!

Comment: Ok, let me try this: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1339#issuecomment-587834601

Comment: Hi, did you get `hostAliases` to work? Also take a look at this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62940403/kubernetes-not-able-pull-image-from-private-registry-having-private-domain-point), there seems to be an issue related to overwriting `etc/hosts` for microk8s.

Comment: Yes, it works. I'm using Helm, and I just follow this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390226/how-to-add-extra-hosts-entries-in-helm-charts/62516999#62516999

Comment: I have added community wiki answer for better visibility of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390226/how-to-add-extra-hosts-entries-in-helm-charts/62516999#62516999) this can be done using Helm custom values and `hostAliases`.

> A helm templated solution to the original question. I tested this with
> helm 3.
>
> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> spec:
>   template:
>     spec:
>     {{- with .Values.hostAliases }}
>       hostAliases:
> {{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
>     {{- end }}
> ```
>
> For values such as:
>
> ```
> hostAliases:
>   - ip: "10.0.0.1"
>     hostnames:
>     - "host.domain.com"
> ```
>
> If the hostAliases is omitted or commented out in the values, the
> hostAliases section is omitted when the template is rendered.